# Как проверить видимость элемента jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Привел тестовый пример с сайта для удобства. 
Вроде бы всё норм: нажатие на кнопку корзины и появление счетчика товаров. После перезагрузки страницы на сайте уже не будет ни кнопки, ни счётчика (т.к в css у счётчика товаров "num" display:none). Просьба помочь, как реализовать проверку условия: если виден элемент счётчик, то спрятать кнопку, иначе - показать кнопку добавления в корзину

```js
$('.add2cart').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).hide();
            $(this).prev('.num').show();

});
```

```css
.num {
   display: none; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="num" type="number" placeholder="кол-во">
<a class="add2cart" href="">
  <img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/38919-200.png" alt="">
</a>
```

Я попытался сделать такое условие:

```
if ( $( ".add2cart" ).length ) {
                $( ".num" ).show();
            } else {
                $( ".num" ).hide();
}
```

Comment: `После перезагрузки страницы на сайте уже не будет ни кнопки` - ну да, кнопка же сама по себе пропадает.

Answer (score -1):

Если нужно убедиться, что у блока нет CSS свойства `display:none`, то подойдёт такой код:

```js
$(function(){
  console.log($('.num').css('display')=='none'?'Да, он невидем!':'Блок видимый')
 })
```

```css
.num{
  display:none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="num"></div>
```

Под вашу задачу:

```
let button=$('button')
if($('.num').css('display')=='none') button.show()
else button.hide()
```

Если ещё ваши селекторы подставить:

```
let button=$('.num')
if($('.add2cart').css('display')=='none') button.show()
else button.hide()
```

Comment: вот такое условие нужно. если виден элемент счётчик, то спрятать кнопку, иначе - показать кнопку добавления в корзину

Comment: @StepanIvanov это же просто if и else подставить: `let button=$('button')
if($('.num').css('display')=='none') button.show()
else button.hide()`

Comment: Изменил ответ, там симпатичнее выглядит.

Answer (score -1):

Если в css стоит

```
.add2cart{
  display: none;
}
```

Тогда достаточно

```
$(function(){
  if($('.num:visible').length > 0)
    $('.add2cart').fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: Тащемта события DOM мутации лучше не использовать, они были удалены из стандарта: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events

Comment: Теперь приходится использовать громоздкие обсёрверы.

Comment: @Diskyp спасибо, буду знать

Comment: Если так не стоит, то как тогда лучше прописать это?

Comment: @StepanIvanov тогда можно поставить в css или дописать в js "else $('.add2cart').fadeOut();"